# Select records that are in the intermediary table that matches a given value/values and records that are not in the intermediary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE Floor (
Id bigint primary key identity(1,1),
Name
)
```

Table assignment serves as an intermediary table to table Floor

```
CREATE TABLE Assignment(
Id bigint primary key identity(1,1),
AccountId bigint,
.
.
FloorId bigint, --foreign key for Id column of floor table
.
.
)
```

How do I select:

1. records from floor table given an XML which contains the accountId that matches accountId in the Assignment table.

Given:

```
DECLARE @accountIdsXML XML = '<AccountId>73</AccountId><AccountId>74</AccountId>'
```

2. records that do not have matches in the Assignment table

Example:

Table values:

```
Floor Table
Id    Name
1     1st Floor
2     2nd Floor
3     3rd Floor
4     4th Floor
5     5th Floor
6     6th Floor
7     7th Floor
8     8th Floor
9     9th Floor
10    10th Floor

Assignment Table
Id    AccountId   FloorId
1     73          1
1     73          2
1     76          3
1     79          4
1     74          5
1     74          6
1     79          7
```

Select Output:

```
Floor table
Id    Name
1     1st Floor  --matches accountid 73
2     2nd Floor  --matches accountid 73
5     5th Floor  --matches accountid 74
6     6th Floor  --matches accountid 74
8     8th Floor  --not in assignment table
9     9th Floor  --not in assignment table
10    10th Floor --not in assignment table
```

I basically want to select floors  that are assigned to the given accountid and unassigned floors.

What I have managed to do

```
DECLARE @accountIdsXML XML = '<AccountId>73</AccountId><AccountId>74</AccountId>'
DECLARE @accountIdsTable as TABLE (Id BIGINT) --table variable to store accountids to be used in the where in operator.

--insert accountids to the table variable
INSERT INTO @accountIdsTable
SELECT [aid].[Col].value('(.)[1]', 'BIGINT') FROM @accountIdsXML.nodes('/AccountId') as [aid]([Col])

SELECT F.* FROM [Assignment] A RIGHT JOIN [Floor] F ON A.FloorId = F.Id
WHERE (A.AccountId IN(SELECT Id from @accountIdsTable) OR F.Id NOT IN (SELECT FloorId FROM Assignment))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't select from Assignment and instead select only from Floor, then on the first WHERE clause you join both of them:

```
SELECT F.* FROM [Floor] F
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM [Assignment] A 
    INNER JOIN @accountIdsTable AI ON AI.Id = A.AccountId     
    WHERE A.FloorId = F.Id
)
OR F.Id NOT IN (SELECT FloorId FROM Assignment)
```

Here's a [link the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abe07/4/0)

Comment: Worked @Gabriel Rainha, tnx